# Loading multiple JSON files to equal number of dictionaries in python

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

How do i load multiple JSON files into python dictionary.

Example:

I have three JSON file (nested or non nested).

I want to convert these JSON files into three dictionaries in python and run some logic onto that dictionaries.

file.1json
file2.json
file3.json

I want :

3 dictionaries accordingly. And use these dictionaries in a function.

Comment: Whats your question ? Is there any error ?

Comment: Just use [json.load](https://pynative.com/python-json-load-and-loads-to-parse-json/) 3 times: `dict1=json.load("file1.json")`, `dict2=json.load("file2.json")`, ... etc.